# One automation with 2 SQLs triggering 2 separate journeys

Tags: journeybuilder, sql, automationstudio

We want to design an automation in Automation Studio that would comprise 2 SQLs. Both queries will populate data into separate data extensions, which we would like to use in 2 separate journeys as entry source. Is it possible that after this automation finishes, it populates the 2 DEs / entry sources, thus triggering the start of the 2 respective journeys ? This automation would run on a daily schedule. Thanks